# How to set a ng-model variable value to null?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've an input field and a button like this:

```
<div class="notes" ng-repeat="n in notes">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Note Date:</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" ng-model="noteDate">
    </div>
    <div class="button" align="center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-primary" ng-click="updateDate(noteDate,$index)">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `updateDate` function:

```
$scope.updateDate = function (dt,i) {    
    console.log(dt);
    if (dt != undefined || dt != null) {
        $scope.data[i].closingDate = new Date(dt).toISOString();
        dt = null;
    }
}
```

This works fine. But the problem is, after giving `date` input for one item in `ng-repeat`, the note value stays. I used `dt=null` to make the value disappear for other items in the loop but it didn't work. How can I remove this value for other items?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `$scope.noteDate = null` as the variable `dt` is not actually bound to the `model` `noteDate`.